# How to create a view that dynamically fills in missing rows of data from a table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, window-functions, recursive-query, gaps-and-islands

I'm looking to create a view that dynamically fills in missing rows of data from a source test_table. The source test_table updates when changes have been made & the latest record is marked by a column current_record indicator as 'Y'. Below is an example:-

TEST_ID 1234 was updated 4 times in the month of January.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
( test_id           NUMBER(10),
  test_name         VARCHAR2(50),
  test_date         DATE,
  age               NUMBER(10),
  current_record    VARCHAR2(1),
  test_data         VARCHAR2(50)
);

Insert into TEST_TABLE (TEST_ID,TEST_NAME,TEST_DATE,AGE,CURRENT_RECORD,TEST_DATA) values (1234,'ABC',to_date('08-JAN-2020 00.00.00','DD-MON-RRRR HH24.MI.SS'),0,null,'DATA1');
Insert into TEST_TABLE (TEST_ID,TEST_NAME,TEST_DATE,AGE,CURRENT_RECORD,TEST_DATA) values (1234,'ABC',to_date('17-JAN-2020 00.00.00','DD-MON-RRRR HH24.MI.SS'),9,null,'DATA2');
Insert into TEST_TABLE (TEST_ID,TEST_NAME,TEST_DATE,AGE,CURRENT_RECORD,TEST_DATA) values (1234,'XYZ',to_date('22-JAN-2020 00.00.00','DD-MON-RRRR HH24.MI.SS'),14,null,'DATA3');
Insert into TEST_TABLE (TEST_ID,TEST_NAME,TEST_DATE,AGE,CURRENT_RECORD,TEST_DATA) values (1234,'XYZ',to_date('31-JAN-2020 00.00.00','DD-MON-RRRR HH24.MI.SS'),23,'Y','DATA4');
```

[image]

The objective is to fill in the missing date ranges with previous records in the dataset. This requires that the TEST_DATE & TEST_AGE increase accordingly. However, the TEST_NAME & TEST_DATA populate for the previous record. The most recent record must only have the 'Y' CURRENT_RECORD

This could be done in PL/SQL but we have been asked to look into a possible create View solution. Below is the expected output:-

The rows in bold exist in the test table & the other rows are dynamically created.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could approach this with a recursive cte to generate the date series. You can then `left join` this with your original table. Finally, you can fill the gaps with `lag()` with handy option `ignore nulls` (wich Oracle supports - unlike most other databases):

```
with cte (test_date, max_date, age) as (
    select min(test_date), max(test_date), min(age) from test_table
    union all
    select test_date + 1, max_date, age + 1 from cte where test_date < max_date
)
select
    coalesce(
        t.test_id, 
        lag(t.test_id) ignore nulls over(order by c.test_date)
    ) test_id,
    coalesce(
        t.test_name, 
        lag(t.test_name) ignore nulls over(order by c.test_date)
    ) test_name,
    c.test_date,
    c.age,
    coalesce(
        t.current_record, 
        lag(t.current_record) ignore nulls over(order by c.test_date)
    ) current_record,
    coalesce(
        t.test_data, 
        lag(t.test_data) ignore nulls over(order by c.test_date)
    ) test_data
from cte c
left join test_table t on t.test_date = c.test_date
order by c.test_date
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=52af8cf027b0b8bfeed25fae0ecc09d3)**:

```
TEST_ID | TEST_NAME | TEST_DATE | AGE | CURRENT_RECORD | TEST_DATA
------: | :-------- | :-------- | --: | :------------- | :--------
   1234 | ABC       | 08-JAN-20 |   0 | null           | DATA1    
   1234 | ABC       | 09-JAN-20 |   1 | null           | DATA1    
   1234 | ABC       | 10-JAN-20 |   2 | null           | DATA1    
   1234 | ABC       | 11-JAN-20 |   3 | null           | DATA1    
   1234 | ABC       | 12-JAN-20 |   4 | null           | DATA1    
   1234 | ABC       | 13-JAN-20 |   5 | null           | DATA1    
   1234 | ABC       | 14-JAN-20 |   6 | null           | DATA1    
   1234 | ABC       | 15-JAN-20 |   7 | null           | DATA1    
   1234 | ABC       | 16-JAN-20 |   8 | null           | DATA1    
   1234 | ABC       | 17-JAN-20 |   9 | null           | DATA2    
   1234 | ABC       | 18-JAN-20 |  10 | null           | DATA2    
   1234 | ABC       | 19-JAN-20 |  11 | null           | DATA2    
   1234 | ABC       | 20-JAN-20 |  12 | null           | DATA2    
   1234 | ABC       | 21-JAN-20 |  13 | null           | DATA2    
   1234 | XYZ       | 22-JAN-20 |  14 | null           | DATA3    
   1234 | XYZ       | 23-JAN-20 |  15 | null           | DATA3    
   1234 | XYZ       | 24-JAN-20 |  16 | null           | DATA3    
   1234 | XYZ       | 25-JAN-20 |  17 | null           | DATA3    
   1234 | XYZ       | 26-JAN-20 |  18 | null           | DATA3    
   1234 | XYZ       | 27-JAN-20 |  19 | null           | DATA3    
   1234 | XYZ       | 28-JAN-20 |  20 | null           | DATA3    
   1234 | XYZ       | 29-JAN-20 |  21 | null           | DATA3    
   1234 | XYZ       | 30-JAN-20 |  22 | null           | DATA3    
   1234 | XYZ       | 31-JAN-20 |  23 | Y              | DATA4
```

---

Actually, option `ignore nulls` for window functions was introduced in Oracle 12 only. If you really are using 11g, as the question tag indicates, then we can emulate `ignore nulls` with a window count and `first_value()`:

```
with cte (test_date, max_date, age) as (
    select min(test_date), max(test_date), min(age) from test_table
    union all
    select test_date + 1, max_date, age + 1 from cte where test_date < max_date
)
select
    first_value(test_id)        over(partition by grp order by test_date) test_name,
    first_value(test_name)      over(partition by grp order by test_date) test_name,
    test_date,
    age,
    first_value(current_record) over(partition by grp order by test_date) current_record,
    first_value(test_data)      over(partition by grp order by test_date) test_data
from (
    select 
        c.test_id,
        t.test_name,
        c.test_date,
        c.age,
        t.current_record,
        t.test_data,
        count(t.test_id) over(order by c.test_date) grp
    from cte c
    left join test_table t on t.test_date = c.test_date
) t
order by test_date
```

---

Finally: if you need to manage multiple `test_id`s:

```
with cte (test_id, test_date, max_date, age) as (
    select test_id, min(test_date), max(test_date), min(age) from test_table group by test_id
    union all
    select test_id, test_date + 1, max_date, age + 1 from cte where test_date < max_date
)
select
    test_id,
    first_value(test_name)      over(partition by test_id, grp order by test_date) test_name,
    test_date,
    age,
    first_value(current_record) over(partition by test_id, grp order by test_date) current_record,
    first_value(test_data)      over(partition by test_id, grp order by test_date) test_data
from (
    select 
        c.test_id,
        t.test_name,
        c.test_date,
        c.age,
        t.current_record,
        t.test_data,
        count(t.test_id) over(partition by c.test_id order by c.test_date) grp
    from cte c
    left join test_table t on t.test_id = c.test_id and t.test_date = c.test_date
) t
order by test_id, test_date
```

Comment: Good answer. I would bet the lag function is not supported by Oracle 11g, which is the version of the question

Comment: @JaimeDrq: window functions, such as `lag()`, have been supported by Oracle for a long time (version 10 at least). But on the other hand, option `ignore nulls` came later, in version 12 - so thanks for pointing out the 11g tag, I updated my answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: I said I would bet, not I would win  the bet :D

Comment: Guys this is really amazing. I can confirm the database is indeed12g. I just need to figure out the next bit where we have multiple test_id in the table.

Comment: @LeeMurray: I updated my answer for mutliple `test_id`s.

Comment: Just noticed the edited version does not update the CURRENT_RECORD or TEST_DATA correctly. I'll work on it and update once i fix.

Comment: @LeeMurray: ah yes, I see the problem. Fixed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, here is the final solution

```
    with cte (test_id, test_date, max_date, age) as (
        select test_id, min(test_date), max(test_date), min(age) from test_table group by test_id
        union all
        select test_id, test_date + 1, max_date, age + 1 from cte where test_date < max_date
    )

    select
        test_id,
        first_value(test_name)      over(partition by test_id,grp order by test_date) test_name,
        test_date,
        age,
        first_value(current_record) over(partition by test_id,grp order by test_date) current_record,
        first_value(test_data)      over(partition by test_id,grp order by test_date) test_data
    from (
        select 
            c.test_id,
            t.test_name,
            c.test_date,
            c.age,
            t.current_record,
            t.test_data,
            count(t.test_id) over(partition by c.test_id  order by c.test_date) grp
        from cte c
        left join test_table t on t.test_id = c.test_id and t.test_date = c.test_date
    ) t
    order by test_id, test_date
```